# Member access within misaligned address 0xbebebebe for type struct ... which requires 4 byte alignment

Tags: c

I have these 2 structs and function (the typedef pointers are unfortunately enforced I can't change them) for a card game

```
typedef struct cardStack {
    struct cardStack *next;
    Card card;
} *CardStack;

typedef struct _game {
    CardStack discardPile;
    CardStack drawPile; 
    CardStack playerHand[4];
    int currentPlayer;
    int previousTurnPlayer;
    int currentTurn;
    int currentTurnMoves;
    int numTurns;
    int topDiscardTurnNumber;
} *Game;

static void addToStack(Card card, CardStack head){  
    CardStack newCard = malloc(sizeof *newCard);
    newCard->card = card;
    newCard->next = NULL;

    if (head->next == NULL) {
        head = newCard;
    } else {    
        CardStack current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newCard;
    }
}
```

I initialise my 4 players' hands, setting next member of the head node to NULL.

```
game->playerHand[0] = malloc(sizeof(CardStack));
game->playerHand[0]->next = NULL;
printf("%p\n", game->playerHand[0]->next);
game->playerHand[1] = malloc(sizeof(CardStack));
game->playerHand[1]->next = NULL;
game->playerHand[2] = malloc(sizeof(CardStack));
game->playerHand[2]->next = NULL;
game->playerHand[3] = malloc(sizeof(CardStack));
game->playerHand[3]->next = NULL;
```

The printf gives me (nil)

I then want to deal 7 cards to each player (add to the end of their hand linked list)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_PLAYERS; j++) {
        Card card = newCard(values[4 * i + j], colors[4 * i + j], suits[4 * i + j]);
        addToStack(card, game->playerHand[j]);
    }
}
```

But I get this error in the function:

```
runtime error: member access within misaligned address 0xbebebebe for type 'struct cardStack', which requires 4 byte alignment
0xbebebebe: note: pointer points here
<memory cannot be printed>

Execution stopped here in addToStack(card=0xf5500ef0, head=0xf5500f10) in Game.c at line 156:

        } else {
                CardStack current = head;
-->             while (current->next != NULL) {
                        current = current->next;
                }
```

I have no idea why I can print the NULL pointer perfectly fine, but when I pass it into the function it gives this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is kindness by `printf` instead of dereferencing a `NULL` pointer and exploding.

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: malloc(sizeof *newCard) is wrong, that only allocates enough space for a pointer.  The subsequent heap corruption is undiagnosable.  Make that sizeof cardStack.

Comment: The two `struct`s are both defined as a pointer type, which will be hard to manage. Try `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(Game));`. That gives the size of a pointer, not the size of the `struct`. A pointer `typedef` is at best confusing, especially when its name contains no hint of that.

Comment: When you `printf` `NULL` the behaviour is *undefined*, not `(nil)`...

Comment: `head = newCard;` in `addToStack()` serves no purpose.  Review that code.  Perhaps  code should be `head->next = newCard;`  Best to post a  `[mcve].